# session always null google chrome netcore mvc iframe

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core, session, iframe, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a net core MVC project that gives an iframe to external sites. But the session is lost when using iframe on other sites.

```
   services.AddSession(opt=> {
              opt.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
              opt.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
              opt.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
          });

   services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
          {
              options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
              options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
          });

          services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opt =>
          {
              opt.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
              opt.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
              opt.Cookie.Name = "MyCookie";                
              opt.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
              opt.LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Index");
          });

          
          services.AddAntiforgery(o => {
              o.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
              o.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
          }) ;
```

session doesn't work when i use the codes above on google chrome . I also tried other samesite mods(Lax,Strict,Unspecified).
Can you see an error in the code? Or do you know a way to do this?

Comment: Hey, @Baris remove your cache (old cookies) and try again.

Comment: not work for me

Comment: Read this article       https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-session-state

Comment: Have you correctly installed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session` package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  `options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;`  instead of `options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;`

try it, I think it will work.

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {                
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
```

Comment: i loss session and cookie when iframe content change.Everything looks normal when iframe is first run(first content,first page)

Comment: i create new project and use same iframe src and work . Although I cleared the browser history and cache many times, I was somehow unable to run it on google chrome.I guess such a situation happened because the project calling the iframe has ssl

Comment: Have you called ```app.useSession()```